# differential equation with exp in solution

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have a problem with understanding solution some differential equation. This equation is:
$$z'(t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_0} (t, \phi(t,x_0)) \cdot z(t)$$
with initial condition $z(0) = 1$.

It comes from the book [Differential equations, dynamical systems, and
an introduction to chaos](https://www.math.upatras.gr/~bountis/files/def-eq.pdf), see page 13.

The authors report that the solution of this differential equation is function:
$$z(t) = \exp\left(\int_0^t  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_0} (s, \phi(s,x_0)\,{\rm d}s\right)$$

I'm trying slove that. In first step via separation of variablos I can compute that:

$$\frac{{\rm d}z}{z} =  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_0} (t, \phi(t,x_0))\,{\rm d}t$$

In next step I'm trying integrate both sides od the equation in limits from $0$ to $t$: 
$$\left.\ln(z)\right|_0^t = \int_0^t  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_0} (s, \phi(s,x_0)\,{\rm d}s$$

Then from definition of logarithm I obtain the following result:

$$z|_0^t = \exp\left(\int_0^t  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_0} (s, \phi(s,x_0)\,{\rm d}s\right)$$

Here is a problem, because on the left side of the equation I have in final form: $z(t) -1$. 
Could someone exlain me why my solution is other than solution from book?
I will be grateful for your help Best regards ;)

Comment: Note that $\left.\ln(z)\right|_0^t = \ln(z(t)) - \ln(z(0)) = \ln[z(t) / z(0)]$

Comment: Inserting bounds should be done in the LHS in the 2nd last equation: $\ln(z(t))-\ln(z(0))=\ln(z(t))-\ln(1) = \ln(z(t))$

Comment: Thanks so much for answers ;)